# Are room divider curtains safe?

Tags: safety

I would like to install a room divider curtain in my office. This is because,

- it would help to keep my office warm.
- we already have the curtains, curtain rail and brackets.
- doors cost ≫£0.

For example,

[image: stock image of a room divider curtain]

My wife says that, as it would be the only curtain in our house, it may present a safety hazard for toddlers.

Are room divider curtains safe? Is there any evidence to support or allay my wife's concerns?

Comment: I found a few different kinds of room divider curtains, such as those that hang from the ceiling, or those that have free-standing frames.  Can you please help us out by showing us more about what kind of curtain you are thinking of?

Comment: Dangling strings, like those for roller blinds or pull cords are unsafe and should be kept out of reach (blinds all come with a thing to attach them to the wall), but I don't see how a curtain of itself would cause a problem. Do you have pictures of the sort of thing you want?

Comment: Question updated :)

Answer (score 1):

In many houses there are curtains in windows and people live with that.
But there are certain dangers to curtains of course:

- strings can be dangerous if they are too long
- rods may be too heavy, or too weak, and may fall off the wall
- children may try climbing the curtains and fall

I would consider a real door... also because it's more sound-proof, and because it's your house and it's worth having nice things in your house long-term.